# Count number of cells in a column that contain data

Tags: variables, excel, for-loop, count, vba

I have this code:

```
Dim first As Integer
Dim Last As Integer
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 17
    first = (ActiveCell.Row + 1)
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Last = (ActiveCell.Row - 1)
    Range("J" & first & ":J" & Last).Select
    Selection.Value = "=J$" & (first - 1)
    Range("A" & Last + 1).Select
Next i
```

and would like to be able to replace the `17` with a variable because some of the workbooks have an extra group.  I can't just count the number of rows as there is information between first and last but in different columns.

Is there  a way to count the number of cells that have data in a set column where the data may not be contiguous (then I can replace the `17` with a variable that is equal to variable -1)?

Answer (score 0):

Found it online: Thanks.

```
n = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
```